Transferring a BluetoothSocket to another activity using a Singleton class returns a NullPointerException
I am trying to transfer a BluetoothSocket object to another activity using the following Singleton pattern:
package com.example.wheelchairapp;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class SingletonSocket {
    private static volatile SingletonSocket instance = null;
    BluetoothSocket socket;

    private SingletonSocket() {
    }

    public static synchronized SingletonSocket getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            return new SingletonSocket();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized void setSocket(BluetoothSocket BTS) {
        this.socket = BTS;
    }

    public synchronized BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }
}

after I get my bluetoothSocket I call this function:
private void manageMyConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
    SingletonSocket singletonSocket = SingletonSocket.getInstance();
    singletonSocket.setSocket(mmSocket);
}

after that I go to the other activity, and there I get my BluetoothSocket using:
SingletonSocket singletonSocket = SingletonSocket.getInstance();
BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = singletonSocket.getSocket();

assert bluetoothSocket != null;
connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);

but the bluetoothSocket equals null here, and an error is thrown.

seems the instance variable is not initialized. Please try with below in the SingletonSocket getInstance() method:
if (instance == null) {
    synchronized (SingletonSocket.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonSocket();
        }
    }
}
return instance;


Oh I missed that, thanks a lot, it finally worked.


"after that I go to the other activity, and there I get my BluetoothSocket".. "the bluetoothSocket equals null and an error is thrown."

The bug is in your getInstance() method (copied below) where you call the private constructor without saving the new object to instance:
public static synchronized SingletonSocket getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        return new SingletonSocket();
    }
    return instance;
}

Fix it like this:
public static synchronized SingletonSocket getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SingletonSocket(); // save a reference to the new object
    }
    return instance;
}

Several other bugs are waiting for you:

call setSocket(null) - It is probably a programming error to allow this, but if you wish to support it you could make your code more clear by adding a separate method which describes the behavior, like closeSocket() or something
call setSocket(socket) where socket is a valid socket, but it's already closed and thus unusable for any other callers who subsequently call getSocket()
call setSocket(socket) where socket is a valid socket, but SingletonSocket already has a valid, non-null socket. This could result in multiple open sockets and unpredictable or confusing behavior with multiple callers involved.

To guard against these, change this:
Socket socket;

to this:
private Socket socket;

And then change your implementation of setSocket() to something like the example below:
public synchronized void setSocket(BluetoothSocket newSocket) {
    if (newSocket == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("socket cannot be null");
    } else if (newSocket.isClosed()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("socket is already closed");
    } else if (socket != null) {
        try {
            // take care of anything necessary with open socket, then close it
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log this
        }
    }

    this.socket = newSocket;
}

Also, it is not necessary to use synchronized() {...} inside the body of your getInstance() method, as suggested in the comments; your method definition is fine. A static method which is also synchronized will be automatically handled by the JVM as described in 17.1 of the Java Language Specification:

A synchronized method (§8.4.3.6) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as this during execution of the body of the method). If the method is static, it locks the monitor associated with the Class object that represents the class in which the method is defined.

This means the JVM will use the Class object for SingletonSocket – that is, SingletonSocket.class – and handle synchronization between threads automatically. Your setSocket() and getSocket() methods are defined differently - they are both synchronized, but not static which means they are instance methods and will both share the same lock object (namely, that of the object instance itself, also described in 17.1 above).
